# IntelliJ not building or running spring-boot project after spring-boot update

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, build

I have a simple Spring-boot application running fine through Spring boot configuration in IntelliJ

But Once I updated to latest 2.1.4 version of spring boot and a couple of dependencies based on that. I was able to do `mvn clean package` and works fine.

IntelliJ version 2018.1.3. IntelliJ acts weird build button doesnt work or show any sign of being clicked. Then If I create a new Spring-boot configuration, I see run button but once clicked nothing happens and then Run button is disabled. Same thing with debug.

1. I tried closing and opening again
2. Deleting and reload maven packages
3. Mark src folder as root
4. Tried running from Application.Java file directly by right click.
   Same thing happens, nothing happens and Run is disabled
5. Nothing wrong with Spring-boot run configurations as I double
   checked
6. I check compiler exclusions and nothing there as well
7. JDK version is selected and tried enabling and re enabling maven
   auto imports. same nothing works
8. tried to delete entire folder and git clone again and still nothing

its as if Intellij doesnt even know I am clicking. It does nothing.

**Update**: Started working on 2019.1 version.

Comment: Try `File`-> `Invalidate Caches / Restart` ...`Invalidate and Restart`..?

Comment: @khmarbaise still nothing

Comment: @Dexters update to the latest IntelliJ IDEA version. If the issue persists, check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for exceptions.

Comment: from what spring-boot version did you upgrade? does the maven goal work (mvn spring-boot:run)? or is it broken in both idea and maven?